# How to remove icon and add ? button in wpf window?

Tags: wpf

I have separate code of both one for remove icon and one for add '?'(help) button. but can anyone help me to do both.
my code is below.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, uint newStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,
               int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,
               IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    const int WM_SETICON = 0x0080;

    private const uint WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP = 0x00000400;
    private const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
    private const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    private const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int SC_CONTEXTHELP = 0xF180;
```

The below code is remove icon.

```
    public static void RemoveIcon(Window window)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;

        // Change the extended window style to not show a window icon
        uint extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WM_SETICON);

        // Update the window's non-client area to reflect the changes
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE |
              SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
```

This function is for add help icon

```
    public static void AddHelpIcon(Window window)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        uint styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        styles &= 0xFFFFFFFF ^ (WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, styles);
        styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE );
        styles |= WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP;
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WM_SETICON);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(window)).AddHook(HelpHook);
        }

        private static IntPtr HelpHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND &&
                ((int)wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_CONTEXTHELP)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("help");
                handled = true;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
       }
```

So can anybody help me for doing both of them in a windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using a `Telerik window` which is best for that. Please try it.